# Max Heap Insertion and Sorting Java

Tags: java, sorting, max-heap

I am trying to construct a Max Heap and as each new value is inserted the value gets shifted up or down into its correct position, I have yet to implement a shift down function so as of right now I'm using a test that should only require the program to shift up. The test data is entered in the following order:

[16, 10, 14, 9, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 3]

I'm using the following code in the main class to insert the values in the heap:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinaryHeap bh = new BinaryHeap();

        bh.insert(16);
        bh.insert(10);
        bh.insert(14);
        bh.insert(9);
        bh.insert(7);
        bh.insert(1);
        bh.insert(4);
        bh.insert(2);
        bh.insert(8);
        bh.insert(3);

        bh.printHeap();

    }
}
```

And this next bit of code is where the insertion and the shifting takes place:

```
package com.company;

public class BinaryHeap {
    private int[] Heap;
    private int size;
    private int maxsize;

    public BinaryHeap(){
        this.maxsize = 10;
        this.size = 0;
        Heap = new int[this.maxsize + 1];
    }

    public int Parent(int i){

        return (i)/2;
    }

    public int LeftChild(int i){

        return (2*i);
    }

    public int RightChild(int i){

        return ((2*1)+1);
    }

    public void insert(int value) {
        if(size <= Heap.length) {
            size++;
            Heap[size] = value;
            siftUp(size);
        }
    }


    private void siftUp(int i) {
        int parentIndex;
        int tmp;

        if (i != 0) {

            parentIndex = Parent(i);

            if (Heap[parentIndex] < Heap[i]) {
                tmp = Heap[parentIndex];
                Heap[parentIndex] = Heap[i];
                Heap[i] = tmp;
                siftUp(parentIndex);
            }

        }

    }

    public void printHeap()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < maxsize; i++) {
            System.out.print(" PARENT : " + Heap[Parent(i)]
                    + " LEFT CHILD : " + Heap[LeftChild(i)]
                    + " RIGHT CHILD :" + Heap[RightChild(i)]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

The shifting function is siftUp() which I think is the issue. When the program is run with these outputs:

```
PARENT : 16 LEFT CHILD : 9 RIGHT CHILD :10
 PARENT : 14 LEFT CHILD : 8 RIGHT CHILD :10
 PARENT : 14 LEFT CHILD : 1 RIGHT CHILD :10
 PARENT : 9 LEFT CHILD : 0 RIGHT CHILD :10
 PARENT : 9 LEFT CHILD : 3 RIGHT CHILD :10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 11
    at com.company.BinaryHeap.printHeap(BinaryHeap.java:61)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

But this isn't correct because 1) the index out of bounds exception at the end which is coming from the printHeap() function and 2)The Children of each parent node are not in the right place, because the root node should be 16 with 14 and 10 as children, also when it prints out the values for the heap, it prints off a 0 however 0 is never inserted into the heap. I've tried doing some of my own debugging but with not much success so any help with this is welcome.

Comment: your  public int RightChild(int i) always return 3. Is that a typo or actually intended?

Comment: That was a typo and I fixed that, but didn't change the output much, Thank you for spotting that though. :)

Comment: Your printHeap() function iterate through 1 to 10. When it calls LeftChild and RightChild inside the forloop, this value will exceed 10 (the last index of the Heap array) when i is greater or equal to 5. That's why you are getting the index out of bounds exception

Comment: Thank you, That got rid of the exception, however it is displaying the numbers in the correct order.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want index 1 to be the root/head of the Heap, not index 0. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void siftUp(int i) {
    int parentIndex;
    int tmp;
    if (i != 0) { // error is this if statement
        parentIndex = Parent(i);
        if (Heap[parentIndex] < Heap[i]) {
            tmp = Heap[parentIndex];
            Heap[parentIndex] = Heap[i];
            Heap[i] = tmp;
            siftUp(parentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The error that is causing your Heap to not displaying the correct number is here inside siftUp, the if statement.

When you insert 16, `Heap[1]` becomes 16. Then, it calls `siftUp(1)`. Inside siftUp, 1 != 0, so the if statements are executed. parentIndex becomes 1/2 = 0, and here comes the problem. Heap[0] = 0 by default is less than Heap[1] = 16. Thus, it swaps the value 16 and 0, moving 16 to index 0 which is not the head as you mentioned. This is just the beginning of the errors, and as you insert more and more numbers, they become all over the place.

Since your root of the Heap is at index 1. You should only sift until index 1, which has no Parent.
After changing the if statement to `if(i > 1)`, and modifying your printHeap(), I get  this output, which I think is correct. You should also print the current value at the current index in the heap.

```
 PARENT: 0 CURRENT: 16 LEFT CHILD : 10 RIGHT CHILD : 14 
 PARENT: 16 CURRENT: 10 LEFT CHILD : 9 RIGHT CHILD : 7
 PARENT: 16 CURRENT: 14 LEFT CHILD : 1 RIGHT CHILD : 4
 PARENT: 10 CURRENT: 9 LEFT CHILD : 2 RIGHT CHILD : 8
 PARENT: 10 CURRENT: 7 LEFT CHILD : 3
 PARENT: 14 CURRENT: 1
 PARENT: 14 CURRENT: 4
 PARENT: 9 CURRENT: 2
 PARENT: 9 CURRENT: 8
```

```
public void printHeap(){
  for (int i = 1; i < maxsize; i++) {
    System.out.print(" PARENT: " + Heap[Parent(i)]);
    System.out.print(" CURRENT: "+ Heap[i]);
    if(LeftChild(i) <=  10){
      System.out.print(" LEFT CHILD " + ": " +  Heap[LeftChild(i)]);
    } 
    if(RightChild(i) <= 10){
      System.out.print(" RIGHT CHILD "+ ": "+  Heap[RightChild(i)]);
      }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```